# Youtube Search Bar not reachable with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, youtube

I am trying to get Selenium to do a Youtube search for me and I got to the final step which is actually entering the text and I'm stuck. searchElem uses the id that allows me to use .click(), but I cannot use send_keys() with that id so I tried inputElem and that doesn't work either.
There isn't a more specific id or class to use for the search input so I'm not sure what to do.
Below is the error I get once I try to use send_keys() with searchElem and inputElem.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <div id="search-input" class="ytd-searchbox-spt"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

This is my code for the WebDriver and elements within the source code.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')

searchElem = driver.find_element_by_id('search-input')
inputElem = driver.find_element_by_id('search')

searchElem.click()
searchElem.send_keys('election')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that `'search'` is the ID of a different element that is being picked up, so try using the `xpath` instead.

```
inputElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/div/ytd-masthead/div[3]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/form/div/div[1]/input')

inputElem.send_keys('election')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the locator based on search field placeholder (this would make it unique)
For example, for english, the placeholder would be "Search" and your locator would look like:

```
//input[@placeholder='Search']
```